# How to get mobile device name details using google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to get mobile model name and details from google analytic. I am using 'gapi.class.php' for getting details.

So far I have tried:

```
requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browser','mobileDeviceBranding','source'),array('visits','pageviews'),array('-visits'))
```

for getting details, since i got

```
Device    Visits    Page/Visit
Apple     145          1.7
Samsung   245          1.33
Apple
```

How can I get further details?

Comment: All dimensions are listed on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets Have you tried `ga:mobileDeviceInfo` or `ga:mobileDeviceModel`?

Comment: yes i got it thanks Eduardo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dimensions `ga:mobileDeviceInfo` and `ga:mobileDeviceModel`.

For a list of all dimensions use the following page:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Please refrain from creating **"How do I get the following info from GA API?"** questions before looking at the link above.